# @QueryParam incorrect parameter type on a Java class

Tags: java, rest, query-string

I have a GET request call as follow and I am getting an

> Incorrect parameter type error

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/apiData")
MyReturnResponse getData(@QueryParam("request") MyRequestClass apiRequest);
```

Here is the request class:

```
public class MyRequestClass {
    @NotNull(message = "application name is required")
    public String applicationName;

    @NotNull(message = "code type is required")
    public String codeType;

    @NotNull(message = "request date is required")
    public String requestDate;
}
```

I am not sure as to why I am getting this. The following are the suggestion from my IDE.

> Be a primitive type.
>   Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument.
>   Have a static method named valueOf or fromString that accepts a 
>   single String argument (see, for example, Integer.valueOf(String)).
>   Have a registered implementation of ParamConverterProvider JAX-RS 
>   extension SPI that returns a ParamConverter instance capable of a 
>   "from string" conversion for the type.
>   Be List, Set or SortedSet, where T satisfies 2, 3 or 4 
>   above. The resulting collection is read-only.

What do I need to do? Please help.

Comment: *I have a GET request call as follow*: so, where is the request? If we don't know wat you're sending, it's harder to tell how to deal with the request.

Comment: Query param must be a primitive value, but you're trying to pass complex structure. You should either use POST instead of GET + `@RequestBody` instead of `@QueryParam` or pass stringified JSON object to `@QueryParam("request") String apiRequestStr` and then deserialize that string into an instance of MyRequestClass (for example via [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson))

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. You can consider using the BeanParam annotation, then your service definition will be:

```
MyReturnResponse getData(@BeanParam MyRequestClass apiRequest);
```

then you need to annotate each parameter on the Java Bean:

```
public class MyRequestClass {
    @QueryParam("name") 
    @NotNull(message = "application name is required")
    public String applicationName;

    @QueryParam
    @NotNull(message = "code type is required")
    public String codeType;

    @QueryParam
    @NotNull(message = "request date is required")
    public String requestDate;
}
```

with this configuration you are able to call the service with a similar request:

```
/apiData?name=ApplicationName&codeType=MyType&requestDate=2021-10-21
```

With BeanParam you are telling the framework that the configuration will be placed on the JavaBean, inside the bean you can define any amount of parameters, not only query parameters, you can include Header, Path and Form parameters if you need (with the appropriate method POST, PUT, etc.)